# how to integrate image crud library in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<?php 
foreach($css_files as $file): ?>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach($js_files as $file): ?>
    <script src="<?php echo $file; ?>"></script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<style type='text/css'>
body
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}
a {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}
a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <a href='<?php echo base_url?>images_examples/example1'>Example 1 - Simple</a> |
        <a href='<?php echo base_url?>images_examples/example2'>Example 2 - Ordering</a> |
        <a href='<?php echo base_url?>images_examples/example3'>Example 3 - With group id</a>
    </div>
    <div style='height:20px;'></div>  
    <div>
        <?php echo $output; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here i upload view file.but i can't able write controller function.i want how to install image_crud library and how to upload multiple images in database and store the image in folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the [image-crud](http://www.grocerycrud.com/image-crud/download) then extract the package

Place the files in the appropriate codeigniter's folder

> config >> image_crud.php
>
> controllers >> images_examples.php
>
> libraries >> image_crud.php, image_moo.php
>
> views >> example.php
>
> Assets in the root of your CI folder

And in your url http://yourproject.localhost/images_examples/example1

Also import the sample database provided in the package